# How can I get `query-replace` to respect `superword-mode`?

Tags: query-replace, words, subword-mode

I'm trying to use `query-replace` with a prefix argument in superword mode.  So for example, `C-u M-% token RET token_drawer RET` should not replace `token` where it appears in `token_width`.  But `query-replace` doesn't seem to respect `superword-mode`.

I have confirmed that `superword-mode` is enabled and that, for example, `M-f` (`forward-word`) respects it.

How can I convince `query-replace` that that `_` in `token_width` should be considered part of a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`superword-mode` defines search functions that can be used to search for word boundaries (see `find-word-boundary-function-table`). The search functions (like qurey-replace) don't use those functions, and can not be made to use them (I guess).

If you would like `_` to be considered as part of a word, then you can modify the syntax table directly using (source evil docs [here](https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#underscore-is-not-a-word-character))

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
```

the motion commands also use that table can use this method as instead of superword-mode (you might have to modify the table for some more characters).

If you prefer not to modify the syntax table, then simply use a regex search with patterns like

```
token\(\[^_]\) => new_pattern\1
```

see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html) and (e.g.) `replace-regex` docstring for the explanation.